# Simple way to post image and comment to users wall with Facebook API

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I simply want to post an image and comment from my own site to the facebook users own wall.

I've looked in various places and through the Facebook API documentation but cant find a straight forward way of achieving what should be a rudimentary task.

FB's own documentation seems overly complex. I have set up the app, along with objects and actions and aggregations from within the graph API tab but can't seem to get what I'm after.

Can anyone suggest a method or article outlining the correct procedure that allows me to pass comment and image parameters, or an article that better deconstructs the problem than FB's own docs.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Downvoter ey? Answer below you quick-draw sourpuss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an app in the developer.facebook.com backend and fill in your APP ID where appropriate below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>Facebook Sharer</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script>
    $(function() 
    {

        $('#share_button').live('click', function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();

            var share_name          = $('input[name="share_name"]').val();
            var share_link          = $('input[name="share_link"]').val();
            var share_image         = $('input[name="share_image"]').val();
            var share_caption       = $('input[name="share_caption"]').val();
            var share_description   = $('input[name="share_description"]').val();

            var share_redirect      = $('input[name="share_redirect"]').val();


            FB.ui(
            {
                method:         'feed',
                name:           share_name,
                link:           share_link,
                picture:        share_image,
                caption:        share_caption,
                description:    share_description
                //message:      ''
            },
            function(response) 
            {
                if (response && response.post_id) 
                {
                    //alert('thanks for sharing!');
                    window.top.location.href = share_redirect;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    //alert('Post was not published.');
                }
            });

            // return false;

        });


    });
    </script>


</head>
<body>



<div id="share_button">share me!</div>



<input type="text" name="share_name" value="Boffins" />
<input type="text" name="share_link" value="http://google.com"/>
<input type="text" name="share_image" value="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/tag-logo-facebook.png"/>
<input type="text" name="share_caption" value="Yes"/>
<input type="text" name="share_description" value="sadfdsdsfasdaffdasfds"/>

<input type="text" name="share_redirect" value=""/>



<div id="fb-root"></div>




<script type="text/javascript">


window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId   : [APP ID],
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true  // parse XFBML
    });

};

(function() 
{
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

</script>





</body>
</html>
```